# Can't connect raspberry Pi3B bluetooth to HC-06 module?

Tags: bluetooth, processing

After my pi crashed I've been trying to set up a bluetooth connection to an Hc-06 BT module. I did it succesfully in the past but I lost the original program with the pi crash. I believe I have followed every step of every tutorial, but somehow it is not working.

What have I done so far:
I did:

- used my phone and a BT serial app to connect to the HC-06 to verify it is working properly, it is!
- let the pi succesfully pair with the HC-06
- let the pi trust the hc-06.
- every time I start my application I run a shell script which is as follows

sudo killall Xvfb

sudo killall java

sudo rfcomm bind rfcomm0 20:14:04:15:23:75 // yes the address is correct here

sudo xvfb-run /home/pi/Documents/application.linux-armv6hf/piTrain

The application I am using is a processing sketch. I have developed a function in order to connect to the bluetooth module. The device behind the BT is an arduino nano. The whole is a handcontroller (<- name of serial object in code). The processing sketch also connects to an other arduino nano via USB. This connection is tested and well. The sketch acts as a bridge between the 2.

Now my memory tells me that performing this line of code would set up the connection in the past:

```
handController = new Serial( this , "/dev/rfcomm0" , 9600 );
```

It no longer does this, so obviously I forgot something to do.

The handshaking function:

```
void handShaking() {
    int b;

    if( handController.available() > 0 ) {
        if( handControllerConnected == false ) {
            handControllerConnected = true;
            println("connection with handcontroller established!");
        }

        b = handController.read();
        dccCentral.write( b );
        println("controller: " + (char) b );

        handControllerTimeout = millis() + 5000 ;
    }

    if(dccCentral.available() > 0 ) {
        b = dccCentral.read();
        handController.write( b );
        println("central: " + (char) b );
    }

    if( millis() > handControllerTimeout ) {

        if( handControllerConnected == true ) {
            handControllerConnected = false;
            println("connection with hand controller lost!");
            handControllerTimeout = millis() + 5000 ;
        }
        else {
            try {
                handController.stop();
            }
            catch ( NullPointerException  e) {
                println(" error terminating connection ");
            }
            try {
                handController = new Serial( this , "/dev/rfcomm0" , 9600 );
                handController.write('$');
                handController.write('$');
                handController.write('9');
                println("attempting to connect with hand controller...");
            } 
            catch(Exception e){
                println("error cannot set up hand controller connection");
            }
            handControllerTimeout = millis() + 10000 ;
        }
    }
}
```

Effectively following line gets called every 10s after I call handController.stop()
new Serial( this , "/dev/rfcomm0" , 9600 );
The output of the program:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./boot.sh 
Can't create device: Device or resource busy
0 /dev/rfcomm0
1 /dev/serial1
2 /dev/ttyAMA0
3 /dev/ttyUSB0
setting up connecton with DCC central
12
respons = hello
respons confirmed, connection with DCC central established
setting up connecton with RS485 bus
connecton set up!
rs485 bus cleared
central:
central: B
central: a
central: s
central:
central: 

central: 
connection with hand controller lost!
attempting to connect with hand controller...
attempting to connect with hand controller...
```

And this goes on for as long as Wifi doesn't crash.

The one thing which is different is my working method. After the crash I wanted the Rpi to be as 'dumb' as possible. I code my processing sketch in VS code on on my windows PC. I use the processing-java command line tool to export the sketch. With scp I transmitt the entire folder over to the rpi and Then I run the boot script.

Also perhaps that this does mean something usefull:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rfcomm connect hci0 20:14:04:15:23:75
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection reset by peer

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0 20:14:04:15:23:75
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused
```

Last time the bluetooth connection was a walk in the park, it just... worked.

Can somebody tell me what it is that I am forgetting or doing wrong?

EDIT:
extra info. In the bluetooth program I got this output. I quickly run info after connect, the auto disconnect still happens

```
[bluetooth]# connect 20:14:04:15:23:75
Attempting to connect to 20:14:04:15:23:75
[CHG] Device 20:14:04:15:23:75 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 20:14:04:15:23:75 ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[Hand Controller]# info 20:14:04:15:23:75
Device 20:14:04:15:23:75 (public)
        Name: Hand Controller
        Alias: Hand Controller
        Class: 0x00001f00
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        LegacyPairing: yes
        UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
[CHG] Device 20:14:04:15:23:75 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 20:14:04:15:23:75 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# info 20:14:04:15:23:75
Device 20:14:04:15:23:75 (public)
        Name: Hand Controller
        Alias: Hand Controller
        Class: 0x00001f00
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: yes
        UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
[bluetooth]#
```

Comment: I have learned that the bluetooth module is automatically disconnecting continously. I am using bluetoothctl. I tried unpairing and untrusting etc, it has no effect. When I connect if automatically disconnects after a few seconds. When I bind, it keeps connecting/disconencting all the time. Why is this? I use the latest raspbian version on my pi 3b btw

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructins to setup my arduino and HC-06 module:
https://www.aranacorp.com/en/arduino-and-bluetooth-module-hc-06/

Which was connecting it up and using the following sketch:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial hc06(2,3);

String cmd="";
float sensor_val=0;

void setup(){
  //Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Initialize Bluetooth Serial Port
  hc06.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  //Read data from HC06
  while(hc06.available()>0){
    cmd+=(char)hc06.read();
  }

  //Select function with cmd
  if(cmd!=""){
    Serial.print("Command recieved : ");
    Serial.println(cmd);
    // We expect ON or OFF from bluetooth
    if(cmd=="ON"){
        Serial.println("Function is on");
    }else if(cmd=="OFF"){
        Serial.println("Function is off");
    }else{
        Serial.println("Function is off by default");
    }
    cmd=""; //reset cmd
  }
  // Simulate sensor measurement
  sensor_val=(float)random(256); // random number between 0 and 255
    
  //Write sensor data to HC06
  hc06.print(sensor_val);
  delay(100);
}
```

Then on my Raspberry Pi did the following to pair the Raspberry Pi to the HC-06:

```
$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Device 00:00:12:06:53:92 LegacyPairing: no
[CHG] Device 00:00:12:06:53:92 Name: HC-06
[CHG] Device 00:00:12:06:53:92 Alias: HC-06
[bluetooth]# scan off
[bluetooth]# pair 00:00:12:06:53:92 
Attempting to pair with 00:00:12:06:53:92
[CHG] Device 00:00:12:06:53:92 Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 1234
[CHG] Device 00:00:12:06:53:92 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:00:12:06:53:92 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 00:00:12:06:53:92 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 00:00:12:06:53:92 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 00:00:12:06:53:92 Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

I have the Blue Dot Python library installed so I used that to create a Bluetooth Serial Client.

I used the documentation at: https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothclient to create the following:

```py
from bluedot.btcomm import BluetoothClient
from signal import pause

def data_received(data):
    print(data)

c = BluetoothClient("00:00:12:06:53:92", data_received)
c.send("ON")

pause()
```

The "ON" command appeared on the Arduino and the randomly generated numbers appeared on my Raspberry

```
$ python hc06.py 
09.00
8
.00
83.00
79.00
81.00
2
48.00
```